# Why is having an abstract subclass of concrete class bad design?

Tags: java, class-design

After all ANY java abstract is an abstract subclass of Object. Sometimes we need to force the subclass to implement some methods, but may already have a pretty well defined hierarchy with concrete classes.

For example: I have a well functioning hierarchy with 
Vehicle<--- Car

and now I want to add ElectricCar to this hierarchy.

vehicle<--Car<--ElectricCar.

I also want all the different types of electric cars to implement certain behaviors like getBatteryLife or something-

Why would it be a bad idea to make ElectricCar abstract ?

Comment: Who says that's bad design?

Answer (score 2):

there's nothing wrong in making it abstract. if your business requires you to make it abstract, it's fine. Like you said, lots of classes in Java lib are abstract and still extending Object.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad, per se. Not common, but not bad. The only thing I can think of is understandability: if I saw a concrete class Car that I could instantiate, I would normally assume that any child of it was also instantiable, because 99% of code works this way.Then I'd be confused, for a second, about not being able to instantiate an ElectricCar.

Answer (score 1):

It could be argued that this pattern breaks the [Liskov Substituion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) since you can't pass "ElectricCar" wherever "Car" is expected if it's declared abstract (you could pass instances of ElectricCar subclasses of course).

In this particular example, the concrete electric cars (hydrogen powered/plug-in/etc?) I would expect to inherit directly from "Car" since they satisfy an "is-a" relationship and are a proper specialisation of "Car".  If you wanted to described some common behaviours and traits they should provide then they should also implement an ElectricCar *interface*.

It seems what you really want is the ability to inherit from Car (since that is what they are) **and** share/re-use common implementations of electric car related methods.  In this case you are looking at a multiple inheritance problem or a need for [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), neither of which are directly supported in Java.

Providing an abstract class in the middle of a concrete hierarchy may be one way around this, but it's not pretty.

Comment: I think the Liskov Substitution Principle is not broken here - you **can** pass every instance of the type ElectricCar whereever Car is needed (at least, if `Car` in general is not something fuel-specific).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would prefer to define an Interface for ElectricCar and then allow the implementing class to define the methods. Then you can share the behavior of getBatteryLife through another mechanism.

I've built some pretty deep hierarchies of Inheritance and I tend to avoid them do to the brittle nature they tend to build up over time. One Base class might make sense, but I would think about how you can compose your object model to share behavior w/o inheritance if possible.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this; an ElectricCar, logically, would be both a Car and an IElectricCar, but since IElectricCar cannot derive from Car, you can't work with an implementor of IElectricCar as both a Car and an IElectricCar at the same time, unless IElectricCar requires its implementors to have the same methods as Car (which violates more sensibilities and design principles than an abstract derivative of a concrete parent).

Comment: I don't use turkish notation so I meant define interface ElectricCar (IElectricCar) which the specific types of cars could implement if they wanted electric car behaviors. I was pointing toward having no imlplementation of ElectricCar but rather having it as an interface only and allowing the specific Car types to implement it if they want that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In you example I would say that supposedly the `Car` class should be abstract (or an interface), too. But there is nothing wrong with the `ElectricCar` being abstract.